Error while trying to export .blend project to GLB
I got this error while i tried to export the blender project to .GLB file.Im using Blender 4.1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 1131, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 39, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 56, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 85, in __gather_gltf
    active_scene_idx, scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 30, in gather_gltf2
    scenes.append(__gather_scene(blender_scene, export_settings))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 36, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 84, in __gather_scene
    node = gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.gather_node(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 48, in gather_node
    children=__gather_children(vnode, export_settings),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 95, in __gather_children
    node = gather_node(c, export_settings)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 42, in gather_node
    mesh = __gather_mesh(vnode, blender_object, export_settings)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 314, in __gather_mesh
    result = gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.gather_mesh(blender_mesh,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 36, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 58, in gather_mesh
    primitives=__gather_primitives(blender_mesh, uuid_for_skined_data, vertex_groups, modifiers, materials, export_settings),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 135, in __gather_primitives
    return gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.gather_primitives(blender_mesh,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 36, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 57, in gather_primitives
    blender_primitives, addional_materials_udim = __gather_cache_primitives(materials, blender_mesh, uuid_for_skined_data,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 36, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 124, in __gather_cache_primitives
    blender_primitives, additional_materials_udim, shared_attributes = gltf2_blender_gather_primitives_extract.extract_primitives(
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives_extract.py", line 30, in extract_primitives
    primitive_creator.manage_material_info() # UVMap & Vertex Color
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives_extract.py", line 398, in manage_material_info
    base_material, material_info = get_base_material(material_idx, self.materials, self.export_settings)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 542, in get_base_material
    material, material_info = gather_material(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 36, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 74, in gather_material
    orm_texture = __gather_orm_texture(blender_material, export_settings)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 304, in __gather_orm_texture
    occlusion = get_socket(blender_material, "Occlusion")
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_search_node_tree.py", line 242, in get_socket
    return get_node_socket(blender_material, type, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_search_node_tree.py", line 206, in get_node_socket
    nodes = [node for node in nodes if check_if_is_linked_to_active_output(node[0].outputs[0], node[1])]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_search_node_tree.py", line 206, in <listcomp>
    nodes = [node for node in nodes if check_if_is_linked_to_active_output(node[0].outputs[0], node[1])]
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_search_node_tree.py", line 425, in check_if_is_linked_to_active_output
    sockets = group_path[-1].outputs
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Material' object has no attribute 'outputs'

What I have figured out there is some error with "occlusion" but I'm not quite sure. Is there any way that i can find the name of the material that is causing this problem?

Hello and welcome. The exporter should have handled the exception gracefully and provide informative error messages rather than crashing or throwing unhandled exceptions. That can only mean that this is a bug. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see Where to Report a Bug
